# Using pandas, how do i loc a value where my column contains lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I have a df, with a column that contains a list.
for example -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
                   'age': [21, 23, 24, 28],
                   'occupation': ['data scientist',  'doctor',  'data analyst', 'engineer'],
                   'knowledge':[['python','c++'], ['python', 'c#'], ['css','js','html'], ['c#']],
                  })
```

now, I want to locate only the rows with 'python' as one of the 'knowledge' values in the list.
how do I do that?

I tried to do: pd.loc[(pd['knowledge'].isin['python'])] and it didn't work

(edited to fix the code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a loop:

```
df[['python' in l for l in df['knowledge']]]
```

output:

```
    name  age      occupation      knowledge
0  name1   21  data scientist  [python, c++]
1  name2   23          doctor   [python, c#]
```

##### alternatives

###### finding any element of a set

keep rows with at least one match

```
search = set(['python', 'js'])
df[[bool(search.intersection(l)) for l in df['knowledge']]]
```

output:

```
    name  age      occupation        knowledge
0  name1   21  data scientist    [python, c++]
1  name2   23          doctor     [python, c#]
2  name3   24    data analyst  [css, js, html]
```

###### matching all elements of a set

all elements need to match

```
search = set(['python', 'c++'])
df[[search <= set(l) for l in df['knowledge']]]
```

output:

```
    name  age      occupation      knowledge
0 name1   21  data scientist  [python, c++]
```

Comment: @NightHawk you can accept this answer as the correct answer so future visitors will see by a glance that the problem was solved and they are at the right place if their issue is similar to yours.

Comment: @LajosArpad Could you help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912044/replace-certain-values-of-one-column-with-different-values-from-a-different-df

Comment: @NightHawk unfortunately no, I'm not very experienced with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to join the list into space separated value, then find it contains your wanted word with word boundry.

```py
m = df['knowledge'].str.join(' ').str.contains(r'\bpython\b')
```

Or you can try `Series.apply`

```py
m = df['knowledge'].apply(lambda l: 'python' in l)
```

```
print(m)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: knowledge, dtype: bool
```

The use boolean indexing to select the `True` rows

```py
print(df[m])

    name  age      occupation      knowledge
0  name1   21  data scientist  [python, c++]
1  name2   23          doctor   [python, c#]
```